# Cannot create android app from an archive \app\libs\appodeal-2.1.11.jar' containing both DEX and Java-bytecode content

Tags: java, android, android-multidex, appodeal

I am trying to add appodeal jar file to my project, but this error occurs:

```
Cannot create android app from an archive app\libs\appodeal-2.1.11.jar' containing both DEX and Java-bytecode content
```

Also android.enableD8=false not works.

I am using buildToolsVersion 3.1.3, gradle-4.8 and multidex-1.0.2 library. How can I resolve this issue? Thanks

Comment: Dear @Pavneet_Singh android.enableD8=false not works which means it is not duplicate of that post.

Comment: got it , thanks for the info

Comment: @Mr.Nobody Did you find any solution, I am getting the same error with appodeal.

Comment: @HumbleCoder See my answer. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use special multidex version of sdk, integrate it instead of regular version. Regards.

https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/appodeal-android/2.1.11/Appodeal-Android-SDK-2.1.11-150318-all-nodex.zip

Answer (score -1):

add  android.enableR8=false in gradle.properties
add  -ignorewarnings in proguard-rules.pro